# Where should I go to farm parts for the Trading Post Auctioneer?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have had the [Trading Post](http://www.wowhead.com/building=145/trading-post) for a while and I would like to complete Auctioning for Parts and make the Auctioneer, but I'm wondering if I'm going to the right place to farm for the items.

I would like to know where in each of the zones for [Super Cooling Module](http://www.wowhead.com/item=118378/super-cooling-module), [Cyclical Power Module](http://www.wowhead.com/item=118379/cyclical-power-module) and [Universal Language Module](http://www.wowhead.com/item=118377/universal-language-module) are some good spots to farm for the items?

I have decent gear so I can make some big pulls, so I am looking for places where the mobs doesn't have much hp and either there are a lot of them or they have a fast respawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly from the comments on the pages you have linked:

**[Super Cooling Module:](http://www.wowhead.com/item=118378/super-cooling-module#comments:id=2077779)**

> I found a great place to grind these out. In Shadowmoon valley there is a little path around the cave used for [Swamplighter Queen](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=33808) filled with Riot Blossoms and Twilight Riverbeast. Just go up and down that path and inside the cave for a lot of little mobs that die really quickly. Just pay attention to those around you as there are a couple quests that lvl 91s need, don't be a meanie!
>   I got two cooling tubes and two radiators after two hours of grinding. Happy hunting!

**[Cyclical Power Module:](http://www.wowhead.com/item=118379/cyclical-power-module#comments:id=2124963)**

> After spending endless hours online searching for information on farming  Cyclical Power Module parts and finding absolutely nothing I decided to go and try different farming spots myself. After trying tons of different spots around Frostfire, Gorgrond, and Spires, I finally found the right one that worked for me. It's in Gorgrond, just south-east of Beastwatch at 50,79 at one of the Bonus Objective areas.
>   There are packs of npcs, mainly these level 93 npcs [Frenzied Forager](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=83449) and [Frenzied Spitter](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=83450). In each pack there are 5-6 npcs, the packs are relatively close together, the npcs only have about 12k health each, and there's approximately 11-12 packs in total spread over the small enclosed area. Their respawn time is extremely quick, and the packs seem to be linked to one another once they die. After killing a certain amount of packs then numerous other packs would all respawn together almost instantly. I don't think I had any time where I wasn't killing them, thus the downtime is very minimal or non-existent.

**[Universal Language Module:](http://www.wowhead.com/item=118377/universal-language-module#comments:id=2133203)**

> After 6.1 they drop off all mobs and creatures in ashran, so its easy enough for non pvp players to go in and hide in a corner of the map and kill mobs for the drop like normal farming, got mine in a hour without having to pvp at all! hope that helps!
>   I spend two hours killing the cat people, the bird people and the flower people around Kor'lok's seat and I had 1  Universal Language Filter and 2  Universal Language Repository drop and I only died once to random PvP. I sold one of the Universal Language Repositories and bought a  Universal Language Compensator for the same price. Finally that stupid exclamation mark is done.

**Notes:**

From other comments it seems the times are optimistic values, but this should get you started. Classes with good AoE damage are your friends for the first two (and maybe also the third). The Ashran parts are the most valueable, if you get duplicates there you probably can buy the rest of the parts from selling those.